# Query Pull Requests by CommitID without Repository ID

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Can I get the Pull Requests by commit ID without providing a repository ID?  I am auditing releases and need information provided by PRs.  I am starting without repository info in the data so currently need to query the Repository api and then associate the commits to the repositories before I can make the Pull Request query.

Additionally, can this be done with a Get requests? It seems like it should be a get request but currently requires a Post with a body. Instead of an additional api, shouldn't the filtering for PR type just be in the uri parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried it with GetPullRequestByProject instead?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20requests%20by%20project?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

Since you already have commit Id, from the response, you can query JSON to retrieve the required information. That will also fulfill the second requirement on GET operation.

Comment: Yes, thank you. We are awaiting a DB implementation. Was hoping to avoid pulling down the whole list each time this is run but this should suffice for now. Thanks again.